# Why were these flags declined?

Tags: support, flagging

Earlier I flagged the following answer as "not an answer" which was declined:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/228849

The answer ends with "Its not working and now i get a blank page when placing the order!" which makes it fairly clear it's not a working solution / answer. Also the similarity with the name of the person who asked the question made me believe it was the same person with a second account and it was just a reply to the answer by mighty_hk that said:

> Try it with 'checkout_submit_all_after' event

As that seemed to be the apparent change to the XML between the question and the "answer". I thought that might be pretty easy to miss for a moderator so tried to explain a bit further in a custom moderator flag but that was fairly quickly declined as well:

> This seems to be an attempt by the OP (using a different account) to reply to the answer from mighty_hk that suggested adding checkout_submit_all_after further down in the XML rather than an answer. I think it should be merged into the question, sorry for the custom flag but my earlier NAA was declined so I thought I'd clarify why it's not an answer. – PeterJ 40 mins ago   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Could you let me know if there was anything wrong with my flagging approach on that answer, perhaps I've missed something but it doesn't seem like an answer to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, that answer should have been deleted.
Moderators are humans too. Sometimes they miss things. :)
Thanks for raising the issue. I deleted the answer.

Comment: Either do things more carefull or just hit "skip" button ... I also flagged this and it was declined too *(not an answer – sv3n Jun 6 at 14:06   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it)*